# I want to load elements from a html file into a div after a selection has been made

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<form action="" name="weatherpod" id="weatherpod" method="post">
<label for="destinations">Destination</label><br />
<select id="destinations" onChange="">
<option value="empty">Select Location</option>
</select>
<div id="location">
</div>
</form>
```

The options are created via a JSON file:

```
$.getJSON('json/destinations.json', function(data) {
    destinations = data['Destinations']
    $.each(data.Destinations, function(i, v) {
        $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.destinationID + '">' +  v.destinationName + '</option>');
    })
});
```

I want to pull elements from a HTML file into the `div#location` once a user has made their selection.

This is what I've tried:

```
$("#destinations").change(function() {
    $("#location").load("/raw_html/" + $(this).val() + "_weather.html #body table");
});
```

However, this doesn't work.  I'm a newbie to jQuery so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

I have tried:

```
$.getJSON('json/destinations.json', function(data) {
    destinations = data['Destinations']

    $.each(data.Destinations, function(i, v) {
    $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.destinationID + '">' + v.destinationName + '</option>');
        var URL = "/raw_html/" + v.destinationID + "_weather.html"
        console.log(URL);
        $("#location").load(URL);
    })
    $("#destinations").change(function() {
    $("#location").load(URL);
 });

 });
```

and it adds the correct URL to the Console log.  How would I add it to the onChange event? Thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure what browser you are using, but if you are working and trying to test locally, and you are using Chrome, it won't load local files. See this post: http://robspangler.com/blog/jquery-load-doesnt-work-in-chrome/

Comment: Is your URL supposed to have spaces?

Comment: @kunalbhat I am working in Firefox, but thanks for that advice.

Comment: @Jack Cole, No the URL is not meant to have any spaces, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: If you're working in firefox, CTRL+SHIFT+K opens up the web console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, have you used Firebug to check the options are appended correctly?

Second, you can use a `console.log` to check that the change is firing and that the file name is being created properly. It might be clearer at this stage to use:

```
var URL = "/raw...
console.log(URL);
$("#location").load(URL);
```

And if you're using Chrome, it won't work (see the first comment).

---

UPDATED:

```
// Loop through appending destinations, but remove the rest from the `each` loop.
$.each(data.Destinations, function(i, v) {
    $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.destinationID + '">' + v.destinationName + '</option>');
});

// Add a change handler for #destinations
$("#destinations").change(function() {
   // When #destinations changes, create the URL using the option value that has been selected
   var URL = "/raw_html/" + $(this).val() + "_weather.html";
   console.log(URL); // Just to check
   $("#location").load(URL);

   // If it's working fine, you can just do this in one line
   // $("#location").load("/raw_html/" + $(this).val() + "_weather.html");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Where would I use console.log, would it be before the jQuery I've used or in place of it?

Comment: Also, I have checked using Firebug and the options have been appended correctly.

Comment: @Ste To start with, just try the example in my answer and see if it appears and what the value of URL is (or whatever you call your variable if you don't like URL).

Comment: It adds the correct URL to the Console log. How would I add it to the onChange event?

Comment: The change function works but when I tried the .load function, it doesn't populate the div#location, once again thanks for your help :)

Comment: It works now, I just had to remove the preceding forward slash from the url in the .load() function thanks to @Nick for you help!